# Windows Forms designer doesn't load due to error in code it generated: Do I 'Ignore and Continue' or edit the code marked 'Do not modify'?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2010, windows-forms-designer

This is my first Windows Forms project, and I'm more than a little confused about how to fix errors with the Windows Forms Designer tool.  I'm hoping someone can help me understand the workflow involved in fixing errors in the designer.

I've been given a template application in VB.NET to modify.  I've gone through something like the following workflow several times: The demo application contains a dropdown list selector where I need a numeric up/down entry.  Shouldn't be hard to change, right?  Having zero training in Visual Studio, I clicked on the object and searched 'properties', hoping to change it there.  No luck.  Following [this flowchart](http://xkcd.com/627/), I then right-clicked the dropdown and selected 'convert', picked a numeric up/down object, and - lo and behold - a numeric up/down entry appeared on the form.

I switched over to the Project.vb file to modify the object's event handler, added a `MessageBox.Show` call to make sure everything was working, and built the project.

I received two errors:

```
Error   2   Type 'MyCorp.ProcessControl.ControlLibrary.ToolStripNumericUpDown' is not defined.  C:\HMI\HMI.Designer.vb  192
Error   3   Type 'Mycorp.ProcessControl.ControlLibrary.ToolStripNumericUpDown' is not defined.  C:\HMI\HMI.Designer.vb  1978
```

The associated source lines read (respectively)

```
192:  Me.tscb_PartNumberSelector = New Mycorp.ProcessControl.ControlLibrary.ToolStripNumericUpDown()
1978: Friend WithEvents tscb_PartNumberSelector As MyCorp.ProcessControl.ControlLibrary.ToolStripNumericUpDown
```

Apparently, I'm using a custom ControlLibrary, and it doesn't have a numeric up/down tool.  Looks like I'll have to go bug whoever's authoring that library to add one, use a system standard NumericUpDown, convert it back to a DropDownList and enter the possible numbers in that list, or use a plain old text entry.  Anything to keep the development moving forward!

So, I clicked on the 'HMI [Design]' tab, which threw a big warning page in my face:

> **To prevent possible data loss before loading the designer, the following errors must be resolved:**
>
> The designer cannot process the code at line 191:
>
> ```
> Me.tscb_PartNumberSelector = New Gentex.ProcessControl.ControlLibrary.ToolStripNumericUpDown()
> ```
>
> The code within the method 'InitializeComponent' is generated by the
>   designer and should not be manually modified. Please remove any
>   changes and try opening the designer again.
>
> *Instances of this error (1)*
>     1.   HMI HMI.Designer.vb Line:191 Column:1
>     Show Call Stack
>
> *Help with this error*
>     Could not find an associated help topic for this error. 
>     Check Windows Forms Design-Time error list
>
> *Forum posts about this error*
>     Search the MSDN Forums for posts related to this error

Fortunately, I have the file Hmi.Designer.vb under version control and can revert everything if necessary, but the changes to be reverted are in functions which sternly warn that they should not be modified.

What's the expected workflow here?

1. Revert all changes to the project and try again.
   This leaves users operating without version control in a tight spot (having to redo the entire project, instead of hitting 'ctrl-z' a few times), and it loses some other changes I made (that are, presumably, not broken).
2. Revert line-by-line changes in the Designer.vb file in code marked 'do not modify'
   This is error-prone because there are multiple places to change the code - In HMI.vb, and several spots in HMI.Designer.vb.
3. Ignore and Continue, and try to revert changes using the designer.
   This seemed to exacerbate the problems I was having and generate duplicate code.

I ended up going with 1, because I couldn't make the others work, but I expect to run into this problem again.  How should I deal with it?

Comment: +1 for XKCD reference ;)

Comment: You'll have to bug whoever's authoring that library.  We can't help you find him.

Comment: @HansPassant - Thanks for taking a look, I know the person who's authoring that library and I can bug them about it. I just don't want to have to sit on my hands and wait for the library to be fixed before  I can continue working on the project. I'd really like to know when I can click 'ignore and continue' and revert the change in the designer or edit the auto-generated code to fix this sort of problem, instead of taking a sledgehammer to it and reverting the entire project to the last commit state.

Comment: When I hit these errors I edit the designer vb file manually to put things right. I know it's not recommended and it is up to you but it is the only way I have been able to fix certain errors without undoing and getting in a mess. Over many years of doing this it has always been the best solution for me :)

Answer (score 1):

The code in the designer is just like any other code, you shouldn't be changing it unless you know both what the old does and what your change does, but if you do do know then it can be done safely.

The major caveat to keep in mind is that the code is read and and then regenerated -- if you put something in there to make it work, but the designer doesn't understand it, you can't use the designer to make further changes.  You'll want to avoid that.

What's the best thing to do at any particular time will change depending upon circumstances, frequently reverting will be the easiest and most straightforward method, but if necessary, editing the generated code can be done safely.

Comment: Reasons why source control is your friend ;)